# Using aws-sdk-s3 ruby to generate a presigned url

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to generate a presigned url for an s3 bucket using Ruby.

```
    client = Aws::S3::Client.new(
      region:               'eu-west-1', #or any other region
      access_key_id:        ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      secret_access_key:    ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    )
    @signer =  Aws::S3::Presigner.new(client: client)
    @signer.presigned_url(
      :put_object,
      bucket: ENV['S3_PROFILES_BUCKET'],
      key: "test-#{SecureRandom.uuid}"
    )
```

I try and take the url that is returned from this, something like:

```
"https://some-bucket.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/test-4ad40444-e907-4748-a025-a12515580450?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIATTSSBDQFDFFX36UU4%2F20191204%2Feu-west-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20191204T002242Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=31b0a90127f43e79462713b101b5fc80146c50f800cfce31c493d206ea142333"
```

When I try and make a POST (or PUT) request to this URL with an image binary (I'm using Postman) I get an error about the signature not being correct.

Comment: Did you double check that all of your ENV variables are set?

Comment: You have to do, HTTP `put` request if you have chosen `put_object` when generating the pre-signed URL

Comment: I tried put and patch, both gave error response